# Image Database Service

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvc, asp.net, database

I created simply database service with get, insert, get all image names and verify exist method.

All images will be store in blob storage with unique filename + postfix size. Next one I have image model, with simple expression for mapping object select, methods for detection Webp format and existing.

All methods:

- `GetAllImageNames()` - return enumerable list of `imageNames`
- `Insert(string filename)` - insert filename
- `site GetImage(string filename)` - return image entity, mapped to
- `ImageModel ImageExist(string filename)` - return true/false
- `Delete(string filename)` - delete file by filename

I wrote the `Image` object entity that represents a database object:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }               
}
```

This is a very simple entity, no comments are needed I think.

**`ImageModel` (object result structure)**:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public ImageSize Size { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Image, ImageModel>> ToModel()
    {
        return image => new ImageModel
        {
            Filename = image.Filename,
            Size = image.Size
        };
    }

    public bool Exists()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename);
    }

    public bool IsWebp()
    {
       //Now implement for now
    }
}
```

This model class is very simply again:

`ToModel()` is a function for mapping to results data.

And finally `DatabaseImageService`:

```
public interface IImageDatabaseService : IRepository<Image>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllImageNames();

    Task Insert(string filename);

    Task Delete(string filename);

    Task<ImageModel> GetImage(string filename);

    Task<bool> ImageExist(string filename);
}
```

`IRepository` is design pattern Repository for manipulation with database operations. It's possible to use it as DI of course. But I like to use it as an inherit interface of the current entity.

```
public class ImageDatabaseService : Repository<Image>, IImageDatabaseService
{
    public ImageDatabaseService(DbContext dbContext, IUnityOfWork unityOfWork) : base(dbContext)
    {
        this.UnityOfWork = unityOfWork;            
    }

    private IUnityOfWork UnityOfWork { get; set; }   

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllImageNames()
    {
        return await this.Select(s => s.Filename).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task Insert(string filename)
    {
        this.InsertAsBatch(filename);
        await this.UnityOfWork.SaveAsync();
    }      

    public async Task Delete(string filename)
    {
        var image = await this.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s =>
            s.Filename.Equals(filename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (image != null)
        {
            this.Remove(image);
            await this.UnityOfWork.SaveAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> ImageExist(string filename)
    {
        var image = await GetImage(filename);
        return image.Exists();
    }

    public async Task<ImageModel> GetImage(string filename)
    {
        return await this.Where(s => s.Filename.Equals(filename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(ImageModel.ToModel()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    private void InsertAsBatch(string filename)
    {
        var image = this.Create();
        image.Filename = filename;
        //possibly another image attributes

        this.Add(image);
    }
}
```

`UnityOfWork` is a design pattern for saving data to my database, used in combination with the Repository pattern.

Comment: Quite frankly I don't see any significant code to review. I do wonder why you bother with the Repository / UnitOfWork patterns: to me these often seem unnecessary overhead that pointlessly abstract away logic and just make you write a lot more code than you need. Check this answer on SO, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059863/648075 .

Comment: What is ImageSize?  Do you mean Size?  If so why the set?  I believe it is read only.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the controversial point: there are very good chances that you do not need a Repository. Why?

- Entity Framework already implements Unif of Work. No need to manually handle anything outside very very special cases.
- There are infinitesimal chances that you'll need to switch to another ORM (and if you will do then you will need to rewrite your service layer because EF-specific code pervades those classes).

Honestly: how many times you actually did it? I think I did it three times (in 20 years) and if I have a service layer (and it is well-written) then it's probably the only part you need to rewrite.

Drop all that code and make your code easy to read, programming is already complicate and error-prone without adding useless complexity.

## Model

Do you actually need read/write properties? Details vary according to the EF version you're using but at least `Image.Id` might be read-only.

Validate your inputs! Is an empty file name valid?

```
public sealed class Image
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string FileName
    {
        get => _fileName;
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                throw new ArgumentException("...");

            _fileName = value;
        }
    }

    public Image(int id, string fileName)
    {
        _id = id;
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    private readonly int _id;
    private string _fileName;
}
```

Please do better than this (for example I hate to throw `ArgumentException` when input is `null`, `ArgumentNullException` should be used instead). If file name can be `null` (in your DB!) then just ignore this. Also note that if not required by your ORM then class should be sealed.

## View Model

Same as above, do you need read/write properties? If not then make the relevant ones read-only.

I'm perplex about the `ToModel()` static method. Is there a good reason you're returning an `Expression` instead of the object itself? If for any reason you need some kind of lazy creation (and for such simple model without any heavy initialisation I can't imagine the reason) then why you're using an expression instead of a simple `Func<T>`?

`Exists()` and `IsWebp()` are named as properties but declared as methods. If the operation might be expensive then you're right to use methods but then you should name them as verb+noun (for example `CheckIfFileExists()`). If they're trivial then just use properties:

```
public bool Exists => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileName);
```

`ImageSize` is declared here but it's not in the model. Do not post partial code  (or, at least, be sure it compiles).

## Service

Asynchronous methods should have the `Async` suffix. It's not required but it's a well-accepted convention and you should follow it.

`InsertAsBatch()` is misleading. Which batch? I see just one parameter. It might be `InsertCore()`, `InsertImpl()` or simply dropped all together because it does not add any value.

In the `Delete()` method you're doing something extremely dangerous: you're swallowing an error. If trying to delete a non existing image is a soft error you may, at least, return a flag (it's what, for example, .NET collection classes do). I'd prefer a good old exception but that's just my opinion. Also do not repeat your code, to search an image you already have `GetImage()` method:

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string fileName)
{
    var image = await GetImage(fileName);
    if (image == null)
        return false;

    this.Remove(image);
    await this.UnityOfWork.SaveAsync();

    return true;
}
```

Whatever you pick be consistent: some methods silently ignore this issue (like `DeleteAsync()` while others will throw at run-time (like `ImageExists()`).

```
public async Task<bool> ImageExistsAsync(string fileName)
    => (await GetImageAsync(fileName))?.Exists() ?? false;
```

Validate your parameters! I can always pass `null` for `fileName` and I don't get any error. Even more serious: decide if `null` is valid or not because in `GetImageAsync()` you're calling `ImageModel.FileName.Equals()` and it'll undoubtedly fail with a tough `NullReferenceException` if that property is `null`.

I'm not sure if `GetAllImages()` should be asynchronous or not. You're reading values from DB and sometimes it might be useful to filter them (*"...all images that contain text ABC..."*) but forcing materialization (even if asynchronous) precludes this possibility. It's also true that you should introduce a separate service method for this then I'd keep it as-is (just adding `async` in the name).

Are `ImageModel.Exists()` and `ImageModel.IsWebp()` used only inside the service? If yes then they should probably be `internal` instead of `public`.

Error handling? I do not see a single line to handle DB errors (for example concurrent updates). Is it everything inside `Repository` base class?

Comment: Thank you for exhausting answer. Its perfect feedback. I will try to update my code. Thanks again! .

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, I don't agree with BCdotWEB.
If you don't follow the patterns you are locking your application to a specific framework. Now you may argue that you're never going to replace the framework however I find that this claim is not true. When you *do* need to change frameworks (i.e. implementation details) you're really going to love the fact that you abstracted it away like a good software engineer. 
Additionally if you don't abstract you probably don't create unit tests of your code and for me this is as important as writing good code.

The code itself seems to do it job and obey the patterns.

Comment: I disagree, with well-written services if you change ORM at most you'll need to rewrite the service layer. Something you have to do anyway because EF specific code already pervades that layer. You're just writing much more code (with a chance to introduce more bugs) without any benefit. BTW...how many times in your entire life did you switch your ORM to something else? It's not even useful for testing (it's pretty easy to mock EF). That said...you're just saying "looks good" then this might be a comment instead of an answer but...in reality there is much more to say about that code.